# How to avoid step into vendor/framework code with Xdebug?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

With VSCODE with PHP Debug extension, using the Xdebug debugger for PHP, there is a way to filter the vendor/framework code when debugging to avoid "step into" that code?

Comment: I usually don't have such problems. Do you use breakpoints?

Comment: Yes, I use breakpoints. Maybe is because I am having exceptions occurring in the db connectors. I will fix this and see if the situation persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example in the official documentation, at https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_set_filter

```
xdebug_set_filter( XDEBUG_FILTER_TRACING, XDEBUG_PATH_EXCLUDE, [ __DIR__ . "/vendor/" ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also exclude paths to be stepped through when debugging - exceptions and debug steps will be ignored in there, breakpoints will be still hit.

Use the configuration `"exclude"` or `"ignore"` in your `launch.json`

```
/* ignore files in 'vendor' folder from being stepped into and exceptions */
"exclude": [
  "**/vendor/**"
]
```

More details at: https://docs.devsense.com/en/vscode/debug/launch-json#ignored-paths